# Why all the coefficients except the first(intercept) are obtaining the value very close to zero(e^-17 or low) in the OLS regression model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-regression, statsmodels

I wrote the following code in python using the **statsmodels** package, to create **OLS** regression model. I tried the code with different data-sets and got the model with all the coefficients values near to zero except the first(intercept) coefficient. What could possibly be wrong with the code ?

```
data1 = pandas.concat([Y, X], axis = 1)
dta = lagmat2ds(data1, mxlg, trim='both', dropex=1)
dtaown = sm.add_constant(dta[:, 0:(mxlg + 1)], prepend = False)
dtajoint = sm.add_constant(dta[:, 0:], prepend = False)
res2down = sm.OLS(dta[:, 0], dtaown).fit()
res2djoint = sm.OLS(dta[:, 0], dtajoint).fit()
```

> Here the *sm* is *statsmodels.api as sm* and for sample testing you can consider the dataset *sm.datasets.spector*.

Comment: What are `sm`, `lagmat2ds`? Also, post the first few lines of your data - `Y|X1|X2...`

Comment: @Mortz Here the sm is statsmodels.api as sm and for sample testing you can consider the dataset sm.datasets.spector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your data is structured - you are modeling `Y` vs `Y|lag Y|constant`. Note that the `OLS` documentation (https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html) states that  -

> No constant is added by the model unless you are using formulas.

So the first value that you see is not the intercept but the coefficient of fitting `Y` vs `Y` - which will be `1.0`.

What you can try to check that you are getting sensible results is to exclude `Y` from the predictors like this -

```
res2down = sm.OLS(dta[:, 0], dtaown[:, 1:]).fit()
```

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for pointing that out. I will surely try the way you mentioned. But the thing is that I want to build regression model which will consider previous i.e lagged values of Y as well as X. How can this be done ?  Can you help me with this ?

Comment: What you are doing right now is fine - just make sure that you exclude `Y` itself from the independent variables. Your current regression model is `Y=f(Y, Lagged_Y, X)`. If you remove `Y` from the right hand side and fit `Y=f(Lagged_Y, X)`  - you should get a meaningful regression

Comment: Okay. Now it is clear to me where the problem is and what should be done to solve this. Can you please help me once more ? Just tell me what should I write in python(the code) to do the required ?

Comment: If `Y` is your first column and you want to use all other columns to regress - use the last line in the answer - `res2down = sm.OLS(dta[:, 0], dtaown[:, 1:]).fit()`

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. You were a great help to me. :)